# Outdated MC server

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server

When I try to get on my servers it says "Outdated Server". I know it's because of the update but what do i need to do to fix it? Do I need to wait for the servers to update or what?

Answer (score 0):

If it's *your* server, update your server's core jar to whatever the current version of MC is, if it's someone else's, launch a compatible version at startup